# Life on surrogates

Tags: society, culture, dystopia

In this dystopian world, ruled by a plutocracy, everyone experience life on surrogates. Due to very intense and effective advertising, ANYTHING can be sold, including stuff we really don't need (a bit like today??);

The inhabitants live their life on surrogates. In such an environment, what could be a surrogate for things like **food**, **sleep** or **sex**?

When I say surrogate I mean something that replaces these things in the same way a place like facebook or tumblr can be considered a surrogate for real social interactions. Obviously one should take nutriment and rest from food and sleep surrogates respectively, but they must not be "the real deal".

Comment: I'd argue that what's sold in fastfood chains already is a lousy surrogate for a proper food.

Comment: @Mołot indeed, but I want something even more detached, (say soylent or worse)

Comment: If the question is, "what could replace food, sleep, or sex," that question is just too broad.

Answer (score 2):

## Food

We are already partially there. It can get worse.

People will eat whatever is available in the "food" section of the shop.
Food companies will sell whatever is cheapest to produce.

Today "cheapest to produce" results in stuff that is at least biologically based, like tofu.

With future technology this can change. If it gets cheaper to build "food" from base chemicals the companies will start to do that.

Without knowing how technology improves it is hard to guess exactly what this "food" will look like, but some type of fat/sugar mix with added vitamins seems likely.

Today many governments subsidize farming.  In your dystopia, they have stopped doing that.  This means actual biological food is going to be much more expensive, and most people simply can't afford it.

In many countries today the quality of food is partly determined by government regulations, but in your dystopia this won't apply.

## Sleep.

As far as we know today, people *need* sleep.  We can do without for short periods, but eventually we fall asleep or die.

However, it is quite possible that future drugs will change that.  Once there are sleep-replacement pills that actually work, people will be eager to take them to add more hours to the week.  In a dystopia, more *working* hours, obviously.

## Sex

Making people give up sex is going to be hard.  There are strong instincts that will make teenagers sneak off and do the deed. Adults too, for that matter.

If people only meet on the Net there will be fewer chances for them to sneak off.  Maybe the thought of actually meeting and touching somebody has become abhorrent.

There *are* drugs that will make people less horny, but why would people take them?  You could mix them in the food, I guess, but it would be hard to get the dosage right.

In some dystopia I have forgotten the title to there is a mandatory computerized doctor that both take blood samples and give medicine injections.  It could be used to adjust dosage properly.

By the way, many anti-depressants have this effect, and these medicines can be useful for keeping people semi-happy in a dystopia anyway. Win-Win!

(You might want to think about where children come from in this society. Cloning, perhaps?)

Comment: I must object to the use of tofu as example of modern surrogate food. Yes, it is true that there are companies selling something they claim to be tofu, but which has nothing in common with real tofu - but real tofu is no less real food than cheese is (a comparison used since tofu, technically, is a type of cheese). As for the sex replacement, what about counting toys as surrogate? There are already toys you can hook to your computer to simulate sex over the net.

Comment: @Mrkvička: Tofu is a food made from soy. It is not made from milk. It cannot possibly be a type of cheese unless soy has been recently reclassified as a mammal.

Comment: It;s not necessarily true that "making people give up sex is going to be hard". It may already have started. See the ubiquitous reports about the startling lack of libido exhibited by the younger generations in Japan. For example, [Japan’s sexual apathy is endangering the global economy](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2013/10/22/japans-sexual-apathy-is-endangering-the-global-economy/?utm_term=.c69b485afaf8) (The Washington Post).

Comment: @AlexP Both normal cheese and tofu is made by curdling and tofu is, thus, technically a type of cheese; a cheese is simply a protein gel (which later, for many hard cheeses, is often dried to a solid). The major difference is that tofu is made by gelling soy proteins whereas cheese is made from gelling (cow) milk proteins (mainly casein). There is also a difference in that one most often uses rennet to initiate the coagulation for cheese whereas one can use a wider range of ways to initiate coagulation in soy milk.

Comment: @Mrkvička: Cheese is curdled milk, with optional further processing. The words "protein" and "gel" do not enter into the definition of cheese; the word "milk" does. On the other hand, although I wouldn't eat it, I have no objection to people who want to call tofu "cheese" if they want to.

Comment: @AlexP It does not really need to be in the word-definition if it's in the science. A cheese is a protein gel, made from milk. And a milk is a protein stabilized oil-in-water emulsion (whereas the word-definition of milk states "liquid produced from mammary glands" and lack the notation of what it actually contains). Soy qualifies for the definition of "a protein stabilized oil-in-water emulsion which has been curdled", but not for how the everyday person would use the words "cheese" and "milk" as is not from an animal. Which is why I have been stressing that it is *technically* a cheese.

Comment: @AlexP If you wish to continue this discussion, then let us [do it in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51658/discussion-between-mrkvicka-and-alexp).

Answer (score 0):

**Drugs**

Almost everything is about brains and their behavior. You can mess with that by using drugs. Fairly easy solution to everything and "sleep" tripping narcs in ecstasy pleasures is clearly a road to dystopian world.

EDIT:
Living on pills, does not waste time from productivity and hooks the people; ideal for plutocracy.